# convert JSON string into php multidimensional array

Tags: php, json, associative-array

How do I get this php string which has been achieved using JSON decode:

```
[
    {
        "rank": 5,
        "day": 1
    },
    {
        "rank": 4,
        "day": 5
    }
]
```

into this php multidimensional array:

```
     {
    [
        0
    ]=>array(2){
        [
            "rank"
        ]=>int(5)[
            "day"
        ]=>int(1)
    }[
        1
    ]=>array(2){
        [
            "rank"
        ]=>int(4)[
            "day"
        ]=>int(5)
    }
}
```

It's so that I can access it by using $multiArray[$x]['day'].  Eg echo $multiArray[0]['day']; produces 1
and echo $multiArray[1]['day']; produces 5.

I've tried json_decode but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `true` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php).

> **assoc**
>
> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Documentation exists for a reason.

```
php > print_r(json_decode('[{"rank":5,"day":1},{"rank":4,"day":5}]', true));
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 5
            [day] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 4
            [day] => 5
        )
)
```